# grant privilege to another user

Tags: oracle

I am logging into oracle as a simple user.I want other user who are logged in to the same database as i am ,be able to see and manipulate tabels and stored procedure.
I used grant privilege to achieve this.

```
        grant  all on tablename to user;
```

but it is not working ie on querying the table it is showing no such table or view exists.
How should i achieve this.

Comment: what you mean by "not working"? any error message?

Comment: The other user may have to use a schema name when accessing the table. eg. `select * from user1.table1`

Comment: @ar, you should create an answer to the question so Niraj can accept it, giving you credit for the solution. That also shows the question as being answered, and it makes it easy for others searching SO to see the answer - they don't have to dig through comments to see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other user may have to use a schema name when accessing the table. eg. select * from user1.table1